# jboss 6.x runtime server shows blank page

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, jboss6.x

I am running my server `JBoss` 6.x runtime server with `eclipse Kepler`.When i run my server i got

```
JBoss 6.x Runtime Server [Started,synchronized]
```

But when access

```
http://localhost:8080/ 
http://localhost:8080/admin-console
```

i got blank page.
i change some settings but nothing help.
i have `xampp` already installed on my windows os.

[image]

- when i started my `jboss` using command prompt,`tomcat` from `xampp` 
  also get started automatically.

All ports are working fine.Server port selected 8080 but still something is missing please anybody help me.

Comment: Can you attach your server boot log?

Comment: No, go to the server installation and get into the log directory, clear the log file, then restart server, and provide that log. This is Eclipse log and will not help in debugging your issue.

Comment: Can from tell the path from where you are capturing the log ??

Comment: C:\Users\Saket\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core\JBoss_6.x_Runtime_Server1435951673105

Comment: While attaching the server in your Eclipse, you must have provided a server directory path, so go to that Jboss server path and provide the log from there ..

Comment: You can see, all these are your Eclipse Jboss logs `org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core`

Comment: C:\Program Files\jboss-6.1.0.Final\server\all\log and i found three files server,log & server.log.2015-07-04 which one u need

Comment: `server.log`. First clear it, then restart your server, and then provide all logs

Comment: Buddy, these logs really doesn't look complete .. Do one thing - clear C:\Program Files\jboss-6.1.0.Final\server\all\log directory, and then paste all the logs generated over there .. Also, I believe if you don't specify then in Jboss you will get "default" server, so I doubt if "all" server is correct (however i am not sure because in Wildfly (jboss) 8, things are different) .. So, also clear C:\Program Files\jboss-6.1.0.Final\server\defalt\log and get the logs from there as well ..

Comment: its too large so i can't post here so pls check this link- http://textuploader.com/irfk

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82379/discussion-between-saket-mittal-and-hagrawal).

Comment: That's why I said clear the directories and then post, so that there will be small log print ..

Comment: is the port number correct?..Because jboss admin console runs in port 9990..you can find this in standalone.xml like  this <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>

Comment: @karthik port number is correct,after started jboss when i access  i got these results                                                            `localhost:8083/admin-console - BLANK PAGE                               
localhost:9999/admin-console - THIS WEB PAGE NOT available                
localhost:8009/admin-console - THIS WEB PAGE NOT available               
localhost:8080 blank page`

Comment: see my answer here - I hope it solves that for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33056623/unexpected-end-of-input-while-loading-javascript-on-a-web-page/36742859#36742859

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the console doesn't work properly with your browser? Can you try another browser? It might also be useful to take a look at the `javascript` error console or check firewall and browser settings.

Answer (score 0):

There is Jboss bug open about this problem: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBAS-9509
The reason for the blank page is that jboss server fails to deploy the root war:

> Deployment "vfs:///C:/Program%20Files/jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/all/deploy/ROOT.war" is in error due to the following reason(s): java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 16: file:/C:/Program Files/jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/all/deploy/ROOT.war/

Uninstall Jboss server and install new one to some location without space in the name like c:\jboss-6.1.0.Final. Then change your eclipse configuration to point to new installation (you might not need to do anything if the ports are the same and there is no path in configuration.)