# Unexpected end of input while loading javascript on a web page

Tags: windows, browser

I have a bit different case of "unexpected end of input" than all the cases I have found so far here in SO and other forums. Frankly, I am stuck.

I have JBoss EAP 6.4 on a CentOS machine. Attempting to open the admin console on a Windows 7 box (all the latest patches from MS) ends with blank white page with most possible cause being an incomplete loading of a .js file:

[Unexpected end of input for protovis JS file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KHca.png)

This happens exactly the same with Firefox, Chrome and IE.

On the other hand, the JBoss admin console opens up fine from a virtualized Linux box on the same Win7 machine and also from separate linux-only boxes. Also, wget in CygWin gets the .js file in question in full. This has lead me to a conclusion that it is not a browser issue but rather that Windows has some devious bug. But how to make sure? I do not use proxies in browsers, I have cleared caches and used incognito-modes - no success.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue today and I have found a solution (or workaround?).
**The root of all evil is Windows service "Base Filtering Engine".
When I had it turned off, then the admin console opened.**

Background info:
When opening the admin console (e.g. http://localhost:9990/console/App.html) I had a blank screen. Checking JS console, I have found:

```
"app.nocache.js:17 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :"
```

Upon reload, various JavaScript errors came.
Checking the JS file (/console/app/app.nocache.js) I have seen an unexpected end of it, so it was syntactically incorrect.

When I reloaded the JS file several times in the browser, it was cut in various ways -> so I had the suspect that some "man in the middle" is playing around.
First checks were the virus busters and the firewall, and after all I have found BFE as scapegoat.

I hope that switching that off has no other bad side effects, but honestly I have not found any other way to solve it -> any enhancement ideas are still welcome.